# How do I make a subfolder of my Github repository pointing to another Github repository

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to make a repository as an interface to a combination of some of my related projects which already exist as individual repository?

For example, I want to have a repository called `my_robotics_project`. Inside the repository I want to have five sub-folders and if you click each sub-folder it will go to one of my robotic project repositories.

Comment: You may choose to build `Organisation` instead. Which is more reliable.

Comment: can you elaborate more?